# Python socket listening failed with error target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sockets

I have run this python script via

```
python myproxy.py
```

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxy.py", line 4, in <module>
    client_socket.connect(('localhost', 5000))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

script:

```
import socket, time

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('localhost', 5000))
serversocket.listen(20) # become a server socket, maximum 20 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    data = client_socket.recv(512)
    print("RECEIVED: %s" % data)
    client_socket.send(data)
```

There are lots of stackoverflow answers talking about this is a firewall issue. I have created an incomming and outgoing firewall rules to allow port 5000 and did not work. Please do not link these questions and unlike previous questions let's avoid making each other disappointed.

I am not a telnet expert but did this try:

Telnet

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is ']'

Microsoft Telnet> open localhost 5000
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5000: Connect failed
Microsoft Telnet> open 127.0.0.1 5000
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5000: Connect failed
Microsoft Telnet>
```

I am using a proxy too. I turned off proxy which did not solve this problem. In general, I prefer to use this script while using a proxy, but turning off the proxy is ok if there is no other option.

How should I solve this problem?

**Update:**

Using

```
client_socket.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 5000))
```

Does not much help:

```
    client_socket.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 5000))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: It is a bit strange that while `connect` fails, `bind` works for me (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/548011).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 'localhost' with socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
Also you need serversocket to be in the server script.

Comment: Thanks, it did not help. I updated the question and put the error there.

Comment: One another problem I noted is that we expect the connection to be a server. I don't know why the place where I have copied the code from has marked it as client than server.

Comment: Try making it work with only accepting clients then sending them data after that you can continue on what you were doing. #If u wanna see my code feel free to ask me for it

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing 'localhost' with the ip-address in the client.

I had nearly the same issue until I replaced in the client (WinSCP in my case) the host name (localhost) with my ip-address.

Especially the local loop (127.0.0.1 or localhost) is not interchangeable with the machine's explicit ip address.